# my .htaccess redirection fails

Tags: php, .htaccess

htaccess is enabled, i have the canonicalization running (no-www to www.)

I'm trying to use htaccess to do the following

```
www.domain.com/page.php?i=Page1
www.domain.com/page.php?i=Page2
```

To

```
www.domain.com/Page1
www.domain.com/Page2
```

I tried using this code snippet, with no luck so far:

```
rewriterule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ page.php?i=$1
```

However I think I'm going the reverse way. I can't find example for this.
I have [this](http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/02/hide-php-url-rewriting-htaccess.html) but I can't make it work.

Comment: Just a quick-hint; when you're writing a regex, it's often a time saver to use a regex testing tool, like regex buddy or regex coatch, so you'll be able to find quickly what match and if not, why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/page\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^i=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/%1? [R=302,L]
```

taken from: http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2009/01/apache-query-string-redirects/

Comment: sorry, pasted the wrong section - if you read the content on that link, you should get it. Updated my answer.

Comment: This webpage has a redirect loop

Comment: Sorry, typo -> change that dollar sign in the RewriteRule to a percent sign - updated my answer

Comment: I get : www.domain.com/Page1?i=Page1

Comment: I need to get rid of the query string after the redirect

Answer (score 0):

You want `www.domain.com/Page1` to be visible in the browser's address bar, but internally that url should actually `/page.php?i=Page1`. In that case the problem is the trailing `/` in your regex:

```
Rewriterule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ page.php?i=$1
                             ^---here
```

Your desired `/Page1` url has no trailing slash, yet your rewrite regex requires one, so the pattern doesn't match, and no rewriting occurs. Try removing the `/` and see if that helps any:

```
Rewriterule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ page.php?i=$1
                             ^---no /
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to parse out the query string you need to access it in a RewriteCond

```
# We need this line because /page.php?i=page.php will cause an infinite loop
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !i=page.php
# Now we parse out the value of i from the query string
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} i=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^page.php /%1  [L]
```