# PHP Redirect standard URLs to SEO URLs

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

I currently use the following rewrite rules:
`RewriteRule ^books/([bc])/([0-9]+)/(.*)/page([0-9]+) books.php?type=$1&id=$2&title=$3&page=$4 [L]

RewriteRule ^books/([bc])/([0-9]+)(.*) books.php?type=$1&id=$2&title=$3 [L]

RewriteRule ^books/(.*) books.php?type=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^books books.php [L]`

What I'd like to add, either using htaccess or PHP, is a redirect from a standard URL format to an SEO URL format.
For example:
`books.php?b=1` `=>` `books/b/1/book-title`
`books.php?c=1` `=>` `books/c/1/category-title`

If this can be done using htaccess it's fine, I don't absolutely need the title, I handle the title using PHP anyway (to redirect to the correct URL in case the title that's entered is incorrect).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See my answer here: [my .htaccess redirection fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933958/my-htaccess-redirection-fails/7934015#7934015)

You'd rewrite it like this (leaving out the title - you'd need php for that):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/books\.php$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^([a-z])=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/%1/%2? [R=302,L]
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, unfortunately. I added the code below the case I posted in the OP (RewriteEngine On is also there), and it won't redirect me from `books.php?b=1`.