# Seo URL using .htaccess not working

Tags: php, .htaccess

My site URL:

```
http://stackcomplete.com/category.php?id=28
```

i used seo URl in `.htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteRule ^category-([0-9]+)\.php$ category.php?id=$1
```

but no changes,what i done wrong??

also i have a filed in my mysql database that `url_for_seo` how can i use in my url
http://stackcomplete.com/category.php/arts

Comment: But your code is working because http://stackcomplete.com/category-28.php and http://stackcomplete.com/category.php?id=28 are same pages.

Comment: i have database column that seo_url it i can show tat like 
http://stackcomplete.com/category.php/arts

Comment: Yes. Your .htaccess works as Lucas says. But, if your trying to make it redirect to http://stackcomplete.com/category-28.php from http://stackcomplete.com/category.php?id=28, then check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933958/my-htaccess-redirection-fails/7934015#7934015

Comment: @LucasWillems how can i use another DB field in URl? check back my question...